# How should child components in React communicate between each other in a clean and maintainable fashion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, architecture

I'm fairly new to React and I'm trying to understand a clean way for child components to communicate with each other.

In a simple component, I know that I can make use of props to pass data to child and callbacks for children to pass data back to parent component.
[image]

In a slightly more complex case, when I have multiple children components in a parent component, the communication between the children gets a little confusing. I'm not sure what I should do for children components of the same level to communicate with each other.
[image]

In my case, I decided that, maybe, I could use `states`. So I will have a `state` value in the parent component, and pass it on the children's props. Similarly, the callback handlers (called from the children component) in the parent component will help to set the states accordingly so that a state value gets passed on from one child to another through React's binding.
[image]

And a pseudo code could look something like:

```
//Inside Parent Component
constructor() {
   //initialise state for the child components
   this.setState({testList: []});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ChildA onSomething={this.onSomethingHandler} testList={this.state.testList} />
            <ChildB onSomethingElse={this.onSomethingElseHandler} testList={this.state.testList} />
        </div>
    );
}

onSomethingHandler(evt):void {
    if(blah.blah.blah) this.setState({testList: this.state.testList.splice().push(evt.value)};
}

onSomethingElseHandler(evt):void {
    //Some other complex biz logic...
    if(blah.blah.blah) this.setState({testList: this.state.testList.splice().push(somethingOtherStuffDueToLogic)};
}

//Inside ChildA Component
export IChildAProps {
    onSomething: (evt)=>void
}

render() {
    //Do some logic from the value in testList property
    if(this.state.testList == blah blah)...

    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onSomething({id:321, value:"wassup! I'm ChildA."})}>ChildA</button>
    )
}

//Inside ChildB Component
export IChildBProps {
    onSomethingElse: (evt)=>void
}

render() {
    //Do some logic from the value in testList property
    if(this.state.testList == blah blah)...

    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onSomething({id:123, value:"yo! I'm ChildB."})}>ChildB</button>
    )
}
```

At this point, I'm starting to wonder if the logic in that 2 handler methods, namely `onSomethingHandler()` and `onSomethingElseHandler()` in the Parent component, should actually be resided inside the child components themselves? I thought of this because those logic look like something the child component should be handling on their own to serve their purpose. The parent component shouldn't do it for them or it might just grow messy. But I've no choice because of how I'm handling their communication. Apart from this, I also created a new state simply just to allow them to communicate.

So far, this is still relatively manageable. But in my own experiment, it has got to a stage where I've children component nested inside another children components that need to communicate across other children components of the same (or sometimes different) level. Using states for communication also meant that I have *many* states all over the place, which doesn't look like a good idea to me. And the parent components ended up with tons of messy callback handler methods to manage all that propagation of data up and down the component tree.

The situation is so messy that I can at most illustrate it as something like so:
[image]

And you can see in the above illustration, `ChildB` ended up having yet another state just to help passing that information between its children components.

I'm sure I'm missing something that I should know about React. The callbacks I'm having in the parent components seem a little too much just to handle data propagation. How should I really organise the communication of children components in a clean and maintainable way?

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you're passing a shared resource (the `testList`) from the parent to all children. I'd advise against that because it's hard to manage and control/synchronize, also what happens if for some reason the instance of this `testList` changes in the parent? What's wrong with simply keeping the way you described in the simple case? When something happens in childA it uses a callback to inform the parent, then the parent decides if childB needs to know about it and if so pass that information by passing new props to childB.

Comment: But what if `ChildB_1` which is inside `ChildB` also needs that piece of information? Do I further propagate that info down? In this case `testList` seem like a shared resource. But I think I've other states like `this.state.panelOpen='true/false'`, `this.state.currentMode=0/1/2`, etc. Somehow, I just keep on coming to situations where I need to pass these information to a number of children components at different levels, which makes me go crazy with all the messy callbacks.

Comment: That's easy, unless I miss something. When you pass information from parent to childB you do that in the `Parent.render` method, it then see that the props for childB are "dirty" so it calls render of childB with the new props. When the `childB.render` method is called it will then call the `childB_1.render` method with the new props which will have this new info. This might seem like a long way of doing something that can be done easier with shared resources, but this actually simplifies things if you think about it, because you never have to worry about the states of other components

Comment: @NitzanTomer Yup, this makes sense! In fact, I just recently found out about this too, that React checks for dirty props to rerender. The only drawback is I must bind the props to a state. So I still ended up creating a number to states for this purpose, but I've greatly reduced the callbacks and unnecessarily states in children components through this. However, I still have to pass props from one component down to another through the tree just to pass information. Often, the intermediary components don't even need the props but they are just passing it down to some other child that needs it.

Comment: Why do you need to bind props to state? A react component should have a render method which is using its state and props to decide how it should be rendered. The component can change its own state (using `setState`) which will cause the component to be rendered again. When a parent wants a child to be rendered again it changes the props of that child. Your parent can use its state in order to create the needed props for a child, but the state shouldn't be bound to the props.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I notice that React won't pick up changes if I don't use state in props. For example, if I had this: `let name='John'` and then `<ChildB_1 name={name} />`, React is not picking up any changes when the variable `name` changes. I have to "bind" or use the state in the prop like this way: `<ChildB_1 name={this.state.name} />` so if I ever change the state later in `ChildB`, which is the parent of `ChildB_1`, through `setState()`, React will then pick up the change. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I haven't faced that problem, but even when using the state like that, i wouldn't say that the props are bound to the state. It's just that you're composing your props using your state. That's just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Every React programmer hits this wall at some point in time. I did too. The answer is to use Redux for state management. You have experienced how tedious it is to use React's native state.

Redux is a state management mechanism which can be used in conjunction with React. So you won't be using React's state, instead you will use Redux.

Redux provides a single store, where the state of entire application is stored. You can access the state in your components using `connect()` method.

But there is a caveat. Not all of the react components are connected to the Redux store. There are two types of components-

- Smart/connected components: Connected to redux store
- Dumb components: Dependent on connected components

The idea is to pass the state from redux store to Connected components via React's `props`. The connected components can directly consume state from the store. The dumb components are not directly connected to the redux store. The connected components also pass the state to the dumb components via `props`. So you see, React's state is bypassed altogether. Now, if you want to change the state, following events must happen-

1. An event is fired from the smart/dumb component.
2. `Actions` are dispatched to the `store`
3. `Reducers` create a new state according to the `actions`.
4. A new state will be stored in the `store`.
5. `Store` will return new state to the connected components via `connect()` through `props`
6. Dumb components will receive new state from connected components through `props`

What are actions and reducers?

Actions are nothing but javascript objects that describe how to change the state.

Reducer is a "pure" function which builds and returns the new state tree according to the action dispatched to the store.

Redux - http://redux.js.org/

Redux-thunk - https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Redux-saga - https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm actually aware of redux, but I was hoping for a vanilla method to solve this so that I don't have to make use of an additional library. I thought this would be better especially if I intend to create components which could be reused by others who may or may not be having redux as one of their dependencies.

Comment: Kudos to your concise explanation.

Comment: @Mihir: hey but how you communicate between child components..??

Answer (score 1):

Most fashion way is using Redux.js (or flux.js) to matain your child components state.

http://redux.js.org/

If you don't like invoke third party js. You can use `refs` property:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [react context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html),

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level

Also, note that Mark Erikson has mentioned in his [blog](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/#the-new-context-api-can-replace-redux),

> Yes, the new context API is going to be great for passing down data to deeply nested components - that's exactly what it was designed for.
>
> If you're only using Redux to avoid passing down props, context could replace Redux - but then you probably didn't need Redux in the first place.
>
> Context also doesn't give you anything like the Redux DevTools, the ability to trace your state updates, middleware to add centralized application logic, and other powerful capabilities that Redux enables.

To handle scenarios you mentioned, context API is a good option and you don't have to use additional libraries for that.